# How can I build up a php form based around my sub-query?

Tags: php, mysql

I am building up a MySQL music database, one which uses I have to build a lot of functions for on my php forms to take the data from the database and output it in a specific way.

One such function is to list all the tourdates that an artist is performing at. I haven't yet written out the page, that's why I'm asking for ideas to help me layout a basis to set this up.

The way I intend for this to work is for the user to look at a pre-set list of artists, once they highlight their specific artist and click a button, the page then loads up and displays the corresponding tour dates that link to that artist.

The way the specific tables in my database are linked is like this.

**Tour Table**

This table holds the artist_id, and lists out all the tours that specific artists are doing. (Note: This table holds the tours, in which the tour dates a are a part of)

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_Tour` (  `Tour_id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,  
`Tour_Name` varchar(32) NOT NULL,  
`Start_date` date NOT NULL,  
`End_date` date NOT NULL,  
`Artist_id` int(11) NOT NULL,  
 PRIMARY KEY  (`Tour_id`),  KEY `Artist_id` (`Artist_id`),  
 CONSTRAINT `tbl_Tour_ibfk_1` 
 FOREIGN KEY (`Artist_id`) REFERENCES `tbl_Artist` (`Artist_id`))
```

**Table Tour Date**

This table  holds the tour dates, the dates in which take place as part of the tour, I want to reference all the tourdates that the specific artist would be doing (Tourdate is linked to tour, so tourdate doesn't have artist_id linked in it directly. It is connected through tour)

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_Tourdate` (  `Tourdate_id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,  
`Tour_Date` date NOT NULL,  
`Country` varchar(32) NOT NULL,  
`Town` varchar(32) NOT NULL,  
`Venue` varchar(32) NOT NULL,  
`Tour_id` int(11) NOT NULL,  PRIMARY KEY  (`Tourdate_id`),  
 KEY `Tour_id` (`Tour_id`),  
 CONSTRAINT `tbl_Tourdate_ibfk_1` 
 FOREIGN KEY (`Tour_id`) REFERENCES `tbl_Tour` (`Tour_id`))
```

I've already set up a sub-query that works to obtain the specific tourdates based on the artist_id set. But I need to incorporate this into a php/html file that a user can interact with.

```
SELECT td.Tour_Date 
FROM tbl_Tourdate td 
WHERE td.Tour_id=(SELECT t.Tour_id 
FROM tbl_Tour t 
WHERE t.Artist_id=2)
```

However I need to build a form around this for a user to simply use. So I need some means of listing the names of the artist, and then when clicked on, it will generate a list of the tour dates linked to the artist they clicked on, on the form. I have no idea where to start in terms of setting up this form. So I was wondering if I can get some suggestions or ideas on how to build it.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Please be more clear about this: As what should the tour list show? I get that it's in the form, but do people have to be able to do anything with it at all? - are you trying to say they can select multiple artists at once? What happens to the list in this situation?

Comment: No, it's simply a means of clicking an artist name and then it will simply list out all their linking tour dates. Nothing else is expected of it.

Comment: I kind of assume you can perform such a task when you can write queries like that. Or do you mean the page isn't allowed to refresh first? In that case we're talking ajax (javascript/jquery). If the page is allowed to refresh you could do it with just php. As for the names of the artists I would recommend a `select` element. You could put something like select2 on it to allow people to search in it. - I'm sorry, it's just not very clear to me.

Comment: I'll re-write it to in a much more informative manner :)

Comment: I was about to answer with a solution that wouldn't require a page reload. However, I'm tired and someone else just placed a decent looking answer, so I'll leave it at that. Comment if you'd like to do it without page reloads and I'll write something up for you.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you can use a single query if you wish to use two tables and use a JOIN condition instead of using a sub-query, as then you can get all the data in one query which should be easier to put into PHP variables.

But surely the data in those two tables could just be merged into one.

This would also remove the sub-query. Having two tables like this seems useless to me, why can't you have the tour name, dates and artist ID in the "Tour Date" table? Having all of the tour-related data in one table.

Then you can have a simple query like this:

```
SELECT Tourdate_id, Tour_Date, Country, Town, Venue
FROM tbl_Tourdate
WHERE artist_id = $id;
```

Then use a PHP loop + HTML table like this:

```
$tours = mysqli_query($dbdb, "SELECT Tourdate_id, Tour_Date, Country, Town, Venue FROM tbl_Tourdate WHERE artist_id = 'x'");
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Country</th>
            <th>Town</th>
            <th>Venue</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody><?
        while(list($Date, $Country, $Town, $Venue) = mysqli_fetch_row($tours)){

            echo"<tr>";
                echo"<td>".$Date."</td>";
                echo"<td>".$Country."</td>";
                echo"<td>".$Town."</td>";
                echo"<td>".$Venue."</td>";
            echo"</tr>";
        } ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

$dbdb needs to be a mysqli_connect construct.

$id in the query can come from an input form, or a GET request from another PHP page.

Just an idea, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by creating the form layout, a *very simple* start would be something along the lines of:

```
<form action="lookup.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="artist">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

That would send an artist's name to a lookup.php script on which you'll apply your working sql query, which will return an array that subsequently will be printed in any way you'd like, @ScottSmudger answer goes through the process of actually printing a table with the query results.

That's a *VERY* basic way to get started, of course, later on you'd like to iterate further and have a dropdown with the artists name already filled, then perform the lookup via ajax and return a json array which will result on a more polished UX.

Comment: Instead of having it refer to an external file, couldn't I just have the sql query within the same file, just bracketed as php code? Php code isn't visable when on display i think.

Comment: @JackRogers of course, just remove lookup.php from the action attribute and that would cause the POST request (in this case, your artist's name) to be sent to the same page. Then, perhaps, you could do if(isset($_POST['artist'])){ //execute mysql query here }

Comment: Something like this? `<?php
if(isset($_POST['artist'])){
  $SearchQuery = "SELECT td.Tour_Date FROM tbl_Tourdate td WHERE td.Tour_id=(SELECT t.Tour_id FROM tbl_Tour t WHERE t.Artist_id=2)";
  mysqli_query($conn, $SearchQuery);
}
?>`

Comment: On the WHERE clause, make sure to change the artist id with the value you got from the previous form, otherwise, you'll always get the tour dates for artist id 2.

Comment: What do you mean previous form? It'll all be on the same form won't it?

Comment: @JackRogers I meant the artists name form.